# How to properly build a project in C# to include tessnet2?

Tags: c#

I created a Windows Form App in Visual Studio 2019 that utilizes the scanner attached on the local machine, and then extract the text from it then display the text on any web app thru a web socket. App runs as expected by clicking `Start` on the interface of visual studio.

But when I try to create a Setup Project, install it in a computer, the app was unable to use the [tessnet2](https://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/). It does not extract the text, it just displays its preview.

Here's a code snippet on how I implemented it:

```
 if (img != null) {
   Directory.CreateDirectory("tempDir");
   TempFileCollection tfc = new TempFileCollection("tempDir", false);
   string tempFile = tfc.AddExtension("png");
   Console.WriteLine(tempFile);
   img.Save(tempFile, ImageFormat.Png);;
   Console.WriteLine("Image Save");

   try {

     var image = new Bitmap(tempFile);
     var ocr = new Tesseract();

     ocr.Init(@ ".\tessdata", "eng", false);
     List < tessnet2.Word > result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);

     //Obtain the texts from OCR result
     String[] texts = result.ConvertAll < String > (delegate(Word w) {
       return w.Text;
     }).ToArray();
     String Result = String.Join(" ", texts);

     foreach(var socket in allSockets.ToList()) {
       socket.Send(Result);
       PlatformInfo.Current.Log.Info(Result);
       PlatformInfo.Current.Log.Info("extracted text sent");
     }

     tfc.Delete();
     PlatformInfo.Current.Log.Info("Tempfile deleted");
     Console.WriteLine(tfc.Count);

   } catch (Exception exception) {
     Console.WriteLine("error dude");
     Console.WriteLine(exception);
   }
 }
```

Here is also a screenshot of the project structure.
[image]

Comment: Was that folder present after installation? I haven't created a Setup project for a good while but, based on that screenshot, it looks like the DLL is in the program folder, rather than a subfolder of the program folder.

Comment: You mean the `tessdata` folder? Yes it is present after the installation.

Comment: Try specifying the path as `Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "tessdata")` instead of `@".\tessdata"`. It may be that the current directory is not what you think it is. If you want the program folder specifically, be specific. Also, I'd suggest that you create your temp files under the user's actual Temp folder, rather than the current directory.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for your suggestion. It actually work now. If I may ask, the generated temp file (which is the `.png`) is not actually deleted. The `tfc.Delete` deleted only the `.tmp` file.